# prevent audio to downloading react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a music app in react. I imported musics but they are going to be downloaded as soon as site loaded and that's not want I want. It should be wait till user click the play button. I try this preload to prevent it but it failed:

```
export let musics = [];
for (let i = 0; i < musicsList.length; i++) {
    let dummyArr = [];
    let newMusic = new Audio(path[i])
    newMusic.preload = 'none'
    dummyArr.push(newMusic);
    dummyArr.push(musicsList[i]);
    dummyArr.push({ nowPlaying: false });
    musics.push(dummyArr);
}
```

musicList is the array that has object of name and duration of musics and path is array that has path of imported files.
thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to do an action.on user click so you can just post your code in onClick method

```js
const Download = () => {
  const onClick = () => { /* your code here */ }
  return (<button onClick={onClick} />);
};
```

Comment: no. I import the musics and when the page loaded it's getting downloaded. I want to stop it